# Trying to iterate through a node get rest return

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to iterate through the data that is returned through my get request.  I am attempting to iterate through it as if were in JSON format, but I am new to this and not sure if it is returning something it recognizes in JSON format or if it is recognizing it as a string, which is why I am unable to get it to recognize things such as info.data.items.  Here is my get request using node, basic authentication.

Here is a sample piece of data that is being returned from my get request and what I am actually trying to iterate through.

> {"data":{"items":[{"date":"2017-02-02","revenue":111,"impressions":000},{"date":"2017-02-03","revenue":123,"impressions":0000,},"message":"Top 2 rows returned."}

```js
function rData(key, secret, account_id) {

  var https = require('https');

  var options = {

    host: 'api.urlhere.com',
    port: 443,
    path: 'path',

    // authentication headers

    headers: {

      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(key + ':' + secret).toString('base64')

    }
  };
  var request = https.get(options, function(res) {

    var body = "";

    res.on('data', function(data) {

      body += data;

    });

    res.on('end', function() {

      //console.log(body);
      callNextFunction(body);
    })

    res.on('error', function(e) {

      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);

    });
  });
}
```

Then here is the next function that I am trying to iterate through the data with.  After it goes through this function i get the error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

```
function callNextFunction(rBody) {

  var rData = rBody;

  console.log("Data transfer sucessful: " + rData); // Works up to this point.

  rData.data.items.forEach(function(info) {

    var rev = info.revenue;
    console.log("Revenue: " + rev);
  })
}
```

Comment: and what is your problem

Comment: JSON is textual data. You need to parse it to turn it into JS objects that can have its properties accessed. `var rData = JSON.parse(rBody);`

Comment: "recognizes in JSON format or if it is recognizing it as a string" – JSON _is_ a string

Comment: You JSON is not complete or valid either. test it here: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: sorry if I didn't explain it completely.  My problem was I was trying to iterate through the JSON data that was pulled back from the API call so I can pass the data I specify along to something else.  The guy below understood my bad english, gave me exactly what I needed.  I figured it out about an hour or two later, but forgot to come back here and comment.  And what squint mentioned was exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your JSON I can see the following issue

> {"data":{"items":[{"date":"2017-02-02","revenue":111,"impressions":000},{"date":"2017-02-03","revenue":123,"impressions":0000,},"message":"Top
>   2 rows returned."}   <--  this should probably be a ']'  not sure

From your question I think you want to access attributes of the data.
Try the following

```
function callNextFunction(rBody) {

  var rData = JSON.parse(rBody);

  console.log("Data transfer sucessful: " + rData); // Works up to this point.
  $.each(rData.data.items, function(i, info) {
    if (info.date) {
       //this info will contain the item with "date" "revenue"...
       var rev = info.revenue;
       console.log("Revenue: " + rev);
    }
    else if (info.message) {
        // this is the information that contains the "message":"Top 2 rows returned."
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I ended up solving it like an hour or two later, and forgot to come back here.  But it was exactly what you mentioned here.  The next post is a small chunk of what ended up working.  Just needed the JSON.parse(rData);

Comment: var rData = rBody;
    
    var rDataParsed = JSON.parse(rData);

   rDataParsed.data.items.forEach(function(item) {       
            
           var date = item.date;